# Element No visible

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am new in automation. I automate one we page of my company website.
During scripting I face situation where while detecting one Label text (colored with Sky Blue) my code written as error
'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with', but label text is properly visible and clickable.

I try all most all way to locate this label element but still error remains as it. So I am assuming that due to Label Text color my webdriver not detecting this label and log this error.

Now my concern is. Is it possible that due to Color used in Label Text wedriver is not considering label as visible.

Kindly Advise.

Thanks in Advance

Adding Code and HTML

```
Public WebElement GetDataSourceListByID(List<WebElement>  Tables){
      WebElement lstSearchFields;    
      WebElement fieldTable = null;
      WebElement weTemp = null;
      String tDataSourceId = null;
      Actions Visible;               

      for(WebElement we : Tables){
          List<WebElement> x = we.findElements(By.xpath("//*/div[contains(@id, 'treeview')]"));           
          for (WebElement c : x ){
              System.out.println("____________"+c.getAttribute("id"));
              c.findElement(By.xpath("//*/span[contains(text(), 'Manage Stores')]")).click();
          }

      }

      return fieldTable;              
    }
```

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCbM8.png)

```
<div class="x-grid-item-container" style="width: 260px;">
<table id="treeview-1165-record-310" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="310" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="  x-grid-row" data-qtip="" data-qtitle="">
<td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent edge-store-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Stores</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   refreshIcon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-311" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="311" data-recordindex="1" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="dvp-tree-node-disabled x-grid-tree-node-expanded  x-grid-row" data-qtip="" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent edge-workfolder-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Search Folders</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-318" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="318" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="dvp-tree-node-disabled  x-grid-row" data-qtip="M_test" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-line" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent edge-workfolder-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">M_test</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-319" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="319" data-recordindex="3" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row" data-qtip="Darshan (3)" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-line" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-end" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf edge-searchfolder-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Darshan (3)</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-312" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="312" data-recordindex="4" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="dvp-tree-node-disabled x-grid-tree-node-expanded  x-grid-row" data-qtip="" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163  edgeThemeColor x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-end-plus x-tree-expander" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent edge-setting"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Manage Data Source</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-322" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="322" data-recordindex="5" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row" data-qtip="" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163  edgeThemeColor x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-empty" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf edge-store-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Manage Stores</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-323" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="323" data-recordindex="6" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row" data-qtip="" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163  edgeThemeColor x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-empty" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf edge-connector-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Manage Connectors</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="treeview-1165-record-324" data-boundview="treeview-1165" data-recordid="324" data-recordindex="7" class="x-grid-item" style=";width:0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="x-grid-tree-node-leaf  x-grid-row" data-qtip="" data-qtitle="">
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1163  edgeThemeColor x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="treecolumn-1163">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-empty" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-end" role="presentation"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" role="presentation" class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf edge-rule-png"><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Manage Rules</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1164  x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="actioncolumn-1164">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col" style="text-align:left;"><img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   no-icon" data-qtip="Refresh"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you share selenium code and HTML code also which have you tried as well???

Comment: Please provide html as formatted code, not image. I can't see any `<label>` tag in you html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made some changes in the for loop alone. kindly replace the below for loop and try to execute the code.

for(WebElement we : Tables)
       {
           List x = we.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[id^='treeview']"));
           for (WebElement c : x )
           {
               System.out.println("____________"+c.getAttribute("id"));
               c.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Manage Stores')]")).click();
           }
       }

I found the id 'treeview' appears at the start of the id value, so I used css selector "id^" - It gives the id's starting with 'treeview'.

Hope your issue gets solved. Post back if any more help needed.

Comment: Thanks Ishekh, Vote my answer if it solved your issue, so others can make use of it..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explicit wait before clicking the button

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Comment: Already try this but not work in my case. Adding HTML Code for more details.